# PayPal Merchant SDK Does Not Work in Live

Tags: paypal

I'm using Merchant SDK (PayPalMerchantSDK.dll, version 2.7.109 + PayPalCoreSDK.dll) for Visual Studio to integrate my website with PayPal. Code example:

```
Dim reqDetails As New SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType()
```

I'm ready to go live, but the code that works in Sandbox does not work in Live. I can't even generate an Express Checkout token. These are the errors I'm getting:

“You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods.”

“Subscription Profiles not supported by Recurring Payment APIs.”

There is a big difference between my Sandbox and Live accounts about which I kept telling people as I was transferred from one person to another on the phone, but to no avail.

In Sandbox, under My Business Setup,  I see

Your payment solution: **PayPal Payments Pro** Change

(The sandbox seller account type is “Business-Pro”.) On the Live business account, I see

Your payment solution: **Express Checkout**

There is no option to change it to PayPal Payments Pro or to anything else. Could this be the cause?

Tech support told me that I needed a downgrade from PayPal Payments Pro to Website Payments Pro 3.0. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are saying there are a lot of things in play.
First all Sandbox pro accounts use the old Website Payments Pro template. If you need to go live, this old type of account can only be setup by a PayPal sales rep. It would require you to have a brand new PayPal Account setup. You cannot downgrade your account because this option was removed in 2012. 
To use the new PayPal Payments Pro Payflow edition setup you have to create a test PayPal Payments Pro account on the Payflow server if you would like to test Recurring Payments in the new platform. 
Here is the link to start the process of setting up a Pro Test account if you have not already setup PayPal Payments Pro, Payflow edition:
 
[PayPal Payments Pro Payflow Edition Setup](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro)

Here is the second part of this, if you need to setup recurring payments through Express Checkout APIs for Digital Goods, you need to have your PayPal account setup for Digital Goods. By default all Sandbox Accounts have this feature turned on
Here is the link for PayPal Digital Goods, it also has the phone number for sales, in case you need it:
[PayPal Digital Goods](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital-goods)

Finally there are a few different Recurring Billing and Subscription Programs through PayPal. Express Checkout and PayPal Payments Standard Subscription buttons do not cost extra. They require that your buyers have a PayPal Account.

Here is a link to create a basic subscription button:

[Subscription Buttons](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/)

There is an extra cost for Recurring Billing if you are using it through a Payflow or a Website Payments Pro account.

Here is a link with additional information for recurring billing:
[Recurring Billing through PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#recurring)